# Unable to net boot Rpi 3B+ from ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: networking, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, oracle-linux, netboot

I'm trying to net boot a cluster of pi 3B+s from an Ubuntu server(18.04). The image I'm trying to net boot is oracle Linux 8.4 (ARM64). I've been following this [tutorial](https://dev.to/weeee/raspberry-pi-cluster-part-1-the-boot-2fe5#fn2) with the dhcp section being replaced with dnsmasq since I don't have a security gateway yet.

I have triple checked the settings and tried reinstalling everything a couple of times. However I cannot get the Pis to net boot. I was wondering if anyone could give some insight on what I'm doing wrong. I'll post my configs below and can add any configs/settings/images etc if miss anything out.

All configs are in this [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/nRCAqsyU) (I think i added them all)

edit: I have just released that the Ubuntu server has not been assigned an ip. On initial install it was 192.168.220.95, however after configuring the network settings it is now 127.0.0.1.

Notes: I am aware of the 3b+ [netboot](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1605) problem and have downgraded the firmware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: This probably wont help anyone because its such a silly mistake but i forgot to recursively change the file permissions for the tftp directory so ended up just making /srv rw access and not /srv/tftp.

To check if this is a problem enter `sudo systemctl status dnsmasq`
if there is an error at the bottom of this status that says permission denied for your tftp directory (error should be in red) the run `sudo chmod -R 777 {directory for all your tftp stuff}`